# Simple PHP Path Question

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, so this is a very simple question. Let's say I have two folders: FolderA and FolderB. Within FolderA, I have a PHP file. Within FolderB, I have a certificate. If I wanted to insert the relative path to the certificate in the PHP file, would this be this path: `../FolderB/Certificate.pem`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution entirely depends on whether or not the file in `FolderA` is at the top of the "include tree".

A better solution would be to use an absolute path, eg

```
// FolderA/file.php

// PHP 5.3 only
$path = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../FolderB/Certificate.pem');

// or if stuck with PHP 5.2 or earlier
$path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/FolderB/Certificate.pem';
```

To illustrate why an absolute path is better, consider this

```
// FolderA/file.php
$path = '../FolderB/Certificate.pem';

// some-other-file-in-the-root-directory.php
include 'FolderA/file.php';
// $path is now incorrect as it points to
// ROOT . '../FolderB/Certificate.pem'
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant relative path, but your solution worked without the first slash. Just wanted to check to make sure it wasn't different in PHP. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Why absolute paths is better in this specific case?

Comment: @sanmai If you include `FolderA/file.php` from somewhere else, the relativity of the path changes. Using an absolute path ensures correctness.

Comment: As I said, I'm not good with PHP, and the files I am using to send push notifications to my iOS apps require me to use a relative path, not an absolute path (I didn't write them). That would have saved me much trouble though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

True.

```
/* FolderA/test.php: */
var_dump(is_file('../FolderB/Certificate.pem'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you involved yourself in [set_include_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) then yes you would be correct!